sls create: Configuration file not found in directory
I want to create basic Hello World sls project, but I get the error:

✖ Configuration file not found in directory "D:\node aws\project-tgg-2"

Here's what I did:
haric@LAPTOP-Q7N9HUP9 MINGW64 /d/node aws
$ sls --version

Serverless ϟ Framework
 • 4.1.7

haric@LAPTOP-Q7N9HUP9 MINGW64 /d/node aws
$ mkdir project-tgg-1
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘project-tgg-1’: File exists

haric@LAPTOP-Q7N9HUP9 MINGW64 /d/node aws
$ mkdir project-tgg-2

haric@LAPTOP-Q7N9HUP9 MINGW64 /d/node aws
$ cd project-tgg-2/

haric@LAPTOP-Q7N9HUP9 MINGW64 /d/node aws/project-tgg-2
$ sls create^C


✖ Configuration file not found in directory "D:\node aws\project-tgg-2"


haric@LAPTOP-Q7N9HUP9 MINGW64 /d/node aws/project-tgg-2
$ sls create --template hello-world


✖ Configuration file not found in directory "D:\node aws\project-tgg-2"


haric@LAPTOP-Q7N9HUP9 MINGW64 /d/node aws/project-tgg-2
$ ^

Screenshot

Try it again, but without any spaces in the directory name. It's just a guess, but many programs cannot handle spaces in filenames or directories.

You have serverless 4 now.
They have a subscription plan now, but the cli is far from done.
If you run create with that version, you will have a bad time.
Run only sls or serverless and create something, they will ask you for a license key.
Try this npm i serverless@3.39.0 -g
And run your command again.

The error tells you that you are missing a configuration file. Either create it in the folder you want to run the command at, or specify where the configuration file is:
sls create --config <filename>

